# Python written CSV is limited by 5 rows

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to export numbers in row of csv. However,  doesnt matter if I want to print it in row or columes, they are all limited by size 5. If the writer exccess 5 , it will rewrite them again. I want csv to record all lines I want to write, not only last 5 lines. This is the code I wrote:

```
with open('Testing.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerows(str(lencenters))
```

and
[this is the csv I got:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCGKb.jpg)

Comment: That's not a CSV, it's a JPG. Please post the actual contents of the CSV file as text, not as it's been interpreted by some spreadsheet program.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to convert the lencenters to str like

```py
writer.writerows(lencenters)
```

The lencenters should be a list of lists representing row fields.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with:

```
import csv

with open('Testing.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for i in range(0,20):
        writer.writerows([[i]])
```